# Extracting post from database using PHP

Tags: php

I can get and insert text from a form input, into my SQL database and I was able to retrieve it on a separate page, but now when I try to retrieve it on the same page as the form it displays a blank white page, none of my code is showing.

I enabled my decoder, but even this is not displaying anything. I feel like it's because I placed the block of code in the wrong area.

Anyway, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/nWRwg0Xj I highlighted the block I'm having an issue with. I put a div around it by the way, but it still did not do anything.

I've tried moving the block of code around many times but it still does not achieve anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysterious empty database entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286241/mysterious-empty-database-entry)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 $template = "anonymous posted: " . $row[0] <br>;
```

It should be

```
 $template = "anonymous posted: " . $row[0] . "<br>";
```

And I would assume you want to print it, not just store in a useless variable. So it should be

```
echo "anonymous posted: " . $row[0] . "<br>";
```

Comment: @julian Try doing `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
               
                        // Extract the inserted text
                       print_r($row);`
and make sure that index 0 exists in $row variable

Comment: it's still not working, and where should i put "print_r($row);"? also do you mean like make sure there's a string in my database for row?

Comment: @julian mysql_fetch_array creates an array where keys are column names. That means that if your table in the DB has 2 columns A and B you will get an array
`$row = array(
   'A' => 'Value of A',
   'B' => 'Value of B',
)`
Which means that $row[0] should not exist. 
However, if this is not working, I would recommend you try and remove the whole part that causes problem and add it back line after line. That's how you should be able to find out which line is causing the white screen and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the extracted data to the page. Also, there were some issues with your loop and your `$template` string.

```
<?php    
    include('mysql-connection.php');

    // Selection
    $selection = "SELECT typed FROM posts";
    $query = mysql_query($selection);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {          
        // Extract the inserted text
        $template = "anonymous posted: " . $row[0] . "<br>";

        echo $template; // <- Here
    }                       
?>
```

On a side note, you're using the deprecated `mysql_*` methods. Consider switching to `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: don't suggest the use of a the MySQL extension which is now depreciated

Comment: @Dagon OP did not use `mysqli` in the section under discussion.

Comment: @Dagon guys it's still not working.. idk what else to do. should i move the php block somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

your while loop is not enclosed in a brackets.

```
    $selection = "SELECT typed FROM posts";

   $query = mysql_query($selection);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
      // Extract the inserted text
    $template = "anonymous posted: " . $row[0]." <br>";
   }
```

Comment: don't suggest the use of a the MySQL extension which is now depreciated

Comment: @raveenanigam none man, idk what to do.. i think it's because my php block code that I'm having trouble with is not in the right spot.